# Remote photography (using android) on Nikon D5600. Auto mode not available

Tags: android, nikon-d5600, snapbridge

I successfully connected my Nikon D5600 to my Samsung S8+. Everything's working fine, pictures are being sent from the camera to my phone, the 'live view' from the camera is being displayed in my phone screen, I can take pictures with my camera if I tap the phone screen.

The problem is: I can't use auto mode with remote photography. The alert I get is: Incompatible exposure mode selected; cannot start remote photography. Select exposure mode M,P,A or S.

How is it that you can't use auto mode and remote photography? It is remote. How am I going to move the buttons or the change the camera configuration in other modes (P,M,A) if I am away from my camera?

Is this a known problem with the Nikon D5600 that you guys are aware of? 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As a non-Nikon user (a Canon user), I see two options:

- **Select the P mode**. It's reasonably similar to the full auto mode. You may need to pop up the flash manually if you have a camera with an integrated flash and wish to use it. You don't need to adjust the settings of the P mode at all, because it does everything apart from popping up the flash automatically.
- **Select the A mode** and dial in the aperture value that you want. This, too, will do auto-exposure...but it gives you control over the depth of field. The aperture is a setting that can very well be the same for all photographs you take.
- **Select the S mode** and dial in the shutter speed value that you want. This, too, will do auto-exposure...but it allows you to ensure that a specific shutter speed be used (fast enough to capture action, for example).

M mode may be useful in flash photography giving you the freedom to adjust the relative brightnesses of the background and of the subject. The longer the exposure, the brighter the background. (This is called mixed lighting - where the subject is lit by flash and the background by ambient lighting)

Personally, I prefer the control over the aperture, and use the A mode. Your camera may also have an Auto-ISO setting which may come in handy using the A or S modes over a long time or in changing light. YMMV.

As for my Canon, I don't even remember if all settings can be controlled from the Canon Camera Connect app. I don't care. I just set roughly the settings I want on the camera, use auto-exposure and then remotely release it.

Comment: hey juhist - I was going to write an answer to this but yours was lookin' good. I edited to add a paragraph. I don't think I changed your intent, but if I did, please feel free to let me know and/or revert the answer. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Just use P mode - it does pretty much everything for you. P stands for Program Automatic - it will set your exposure for you, but allows you full control over your settings, unlike the actual Auto mode. If you need more explanation than this about the modes you can always download the manual.

Comment: would you provide some details to describe why using P mode will effectively produce the same results as Auto?  Your answer is essentially correct, but a bit brief and a new user might be uncertain as to why it should work.

Comment: You've answered the *what* but not the **why**.

Comment: The why is pretty much up to Nikon isn't it?

Comment: Speculation: Full "Auto" modes tend to do things very counterproductive to remote operation, like automatically popping up the built in flash, activate multi-frame modes, or automatically mess with settings that will affect the remote control connection itself. OR there is a taxation/legal reason, maybe the device would count as eg a surveillance device if allowing full remote control and full unattended operation...